# Remove specific character from code

Tags: vim, merge, meld

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [^M at the end of every line in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110678/m-at-the-end-of-every-line-in-vim)

After merging project with *Meld* at the end of each line in code apperead such symbols **^M**.
They only visible in *Vim*. What does this symbols mean and how to remove all of them in simple way?

Comment: This has about 20 duplicates, check also http://stackoverflow.com/q/5843495/557306 http://stackoverflow.com/q/3260293/557306 http://stackoverflow.com/q/64749/557306 http://stackoverflow.com/q/3852868/557306

Comment: Not possible -- it's the same problem. Read the second comment on the question for a good explanation in this thread.

Comment: Heh. Your right. Just can't find related topics to this case. 
Search doesn't perceives this symbol.
Sorry for post duplication and thx for explanation.

Comment: You can also highlight the character/word you want gone, hit * to save it in the search buffer, then :%s/<hit Ctrl+r followed by />//g.  If you needed a generic answer.